# Extracting lines with only 1 word?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

Trying to get only the lines that contain 1 word in them.

The current method gets the correct results but sometimes the input file has more than 4 lines inbetween each word. So need a way to **get only the lines that contain 1 word in them.** Any ideas?

Here's an example of what the input text looks like:

```
adversary
someone who offers opposition
The students are united by shared suffering, and by a common adversary. 
— New York Times (Nov 10, 2014)
aplomb
great coolness and composure under strain
I wish I had handled it with aplomb. 
— New York Times (May 18, 2014)
apprehensive
```

So the output should look like:

```
adversary
aplomb
apprehensive
```

Here is the code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Process {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileNameOutput = "OutputFile.txt";
        String fileName = "InputWords";

        try (BufferedReader bReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))){

            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileNameOutput); 
            int lineNum = 0;
            String line = null;

            while ( (line = bReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
               lineNum++;

             if ( lineNum % 4 == 0 ) continue;


                outputStream.println(line);


            }
                outputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

Thanks for your time.

---

EDIT

Getting this error from console from the suggested fixes below.

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Process.main(Process.java:20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "word":

- A sequence of *letters*
- A sequence of any character that is not a whitespace
- A glyph representing a word (e.g. in Chinese)

Lets stick with the first two, and use regex to check, so we can easily ignore leading and trailing whitespace too. Here are three ways:

```java
if (line.matches("\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*")) // One or more ASCII letters
    outputStream.println(line);
```

```java
if (line.matches("\\s*\\p{L}+\\s*")) // One or more Unicode letters
    outputStream.println(line);
```

```java
if (line.matches("\\s*\\S+\\s*")) // One or more non-space characters
    outputStream.println(line);
```

---

As for the `MalformedInputException`, it is caused by a code page mismatch (the exception is thrown by `StreamDecoder`).

`newBufferedReader(path)` reads the file in UTF-8, and the file is likely in the system default code page, not in UTF-8.

Use `newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I gave this a try but still get the error in the description... Any idea as to why?

Comment: Yeah, [`newBufferedReader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-) reads the file in UTF-8, and the file is likely not in UTF-8, but the system default codepage. Use `newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())` instead.

Comment: But the code works fine without any of the edits anyone here suggested. So that can't be the problem.

Comment: Since error happens in `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and nobody has told you to change that call, the error is not caused by what we're saying.

Comment: The error is caused by the `—` character, which is not a [MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm) sign, but an [EM DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Well, instead of the

```
if ( lineNum % 4 == 0 ) continue;
```

condition, you can simply check whether the line you just read contains more than one token :

```
if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;
```

or

```
if (line.indexOf(" ") >= 0) continue;
```

The latter condition should be more efficient than the former.

Comment: Ahh awesome, trying them now. Cheers!

Comment: yeah gives an error... (MalformedInputException: Input length = 1)

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte What line of code gives that exception?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to find that out. You mean this? 
 " at Process.main(Process.java:20) "

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte What's in line 20 of Process.java?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the

```
if ( lineNum % 4 == 0 ) continue;
```

simply check line contains space.

```
if(line.trim().contains(" ")) continue;
```

Comment: "The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char) "

Comment: hmm thanks but still getting this damn error for some reason, even with this suggestion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You get an error saying   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) so is not finding the input file ...
Try changing the filename

```
String fileName = "InputWords";

to

String fileName = "InputWords.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

Working !! need to add the charset.

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
        //testAnimal();
         String fileNameOutput = "OutputFile.txt";
            String fileName = "InputWords.txt";

            Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset() ;
            try (BufferedReader bReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName), cs)){

                PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileNameOutput); 
                int lineNum = 0;
                String line = null;

                while ( (line = bReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                   lineNum++;

                  if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;


                    outputStream.println(line);


                }
                    outputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


   }
```